# Some functions/methods not exported into static library - Visual Studio 2019 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

Apologies if this is an ill formed question. But it is something I don't even know where to start debugging.

I have a library, in which I keep general purpose code. i build this as a static library to include in my projects. The library and the projects are written in C++ and built in Visual Studio 2019.

I have just made some modifications to some code (which happens to be for dealing with times and dates) and suddenly most of my functions and methods within the .cpp file in question are no longer exported into my static library.

I am now getting unresolved symbols linker errors when I try to use these functions/methods. I have run
`dumpbin /symbols /exports mylibrary.lib > exports.txt`
and searching this output, shows that only a handful of symbols associated with my function/method definitions are listed. Symbols are missing for most of my methods, including those for which I have linker errors.

My questions are - have I done enough to show that my functions are not being exported - i.e. is `dumpbin /symbols /exports` the correct command to use? And secondly, if I have performed that check correctly, how is it possible that I have only exported some of my methods/functions and are there any steps I can take to fix it or debug further? I did not even realise this was possible when building a static lib.

Please note I am building a static lib, not an import lib or a dll.

Edit:

One example of a method not being exported is

```
constexpr int sci::UtcTime::getYear() const
{
    return m_cTime.tm_year+1900;
}
```

where `sci` is a namespace, `UtcTime` is my time related class and `m_cTime` is a `std::tm` member variable of `UtcTime`.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding everything and even rebooting my computer in desperation.

Edit 2:
Removing `constexpr` seems to result in the symbol being exported and resolves the linker problems. Why would that be the case?

Comment: Are you using templates?

Comment: no, I'm not using templates.

Comment: It might be the `constexpr` doing that. Was it present earlier? If there's no place where compiler cannot evaluate the calls at compile time, it might not be emitting it at all. [A constexpr specifier used in a function or static member variable (since C++17) declaration implies inline.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, `constexpr` is implying `inline` which causes compiler to not emit the symbol at all.

> [A constexpr specifier used in a function or static member variable (since C++17) declaration implies inline.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

Your edit is also empirical proof that that's the case. I would say it is working as expected. The choice is now yours about whether you want the function to be exported or be `constexpr` qualified.

As for why you have started seeing this now, VC++ has been undergoing compliance related changes for the past 5 years or so, and generally each release is more compliant with the latest language standard at the time of release than previous releases.

Comment: I suspect you are correct. But the strange thing is, this method

```constexpr void sci::UtcTime::set(int year, unsigned int month, unsigned int dayOfMonth, unsigned int hour, unsigned int minute, double second)``` is exported

Comment: Oh, but of course the choice of whether to actually inline a function is made by the compiler. Perhaps the compiler chose to inline the simple getYear method, but chose not to inline the more complex set method?

Comment: VC is full of idiosyncrasies and self-contradictions. Try that in gcc and see what happens. Although, gcc will likely not understand `__dllexport()` if that's what you are using.

Comment: From this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline, my understanding is that a compile error should have occurred because the method definitions were not accessible to the functional block. This compilation error would certainly have made my debugging much easier. I've generated a minimal example and submitted a bug report to msdn.